# From DataTable1, need to fetch values according to Rows and Columns and assign value to new DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

Example data from DataTable - 1

```
-----------------------------
  ID  |   ORG  | DES | A | B|
-----------------------------
 101  |  ABC   | KIL | 1 | 5|
_____________________________
 102  |  XYZ   | LOU | 2 | 6|
_____________________________
 103  |  MNO   | HYT | 3 | 7|
_____________________________
 104  |  PQR   | HYT | 4 | 8|
```

Need to convert it to the following format

DataTable - 2

```
--------------------------------
  ID  |   ORG  | DES | Type | B|
--------------------------------
 101  |  ABC   | KIL | A    | 1|
________________________________
 101  |  ABC   | KIL | B    | 5|
________________________________
 102  |  XYZ   | LOU | A    | 2|
________________________________
 102  |  XYZ   | LOU | B    | 6|
________________________________
 103  |  MNO   | HYT | A    | 3|
________________________________
 103  |  MNO   | HYT | B    | 7|
________________________________
 104  |  PQR   | HYT | A    | 4|
________________________________
 104  |  PQR   | HYT | B    | 8|
________________________________
```

I would like to do this using C#

Comment: Hi Rajkumar! What have you already tried?  Remember, SO isn't here to write your code for you. It's here to help you solve problems in the code you have already written.

Comment: in above code, A, B is dynamic, sometime it comes as A,B,C or S,T or X,Y

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("ORG", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("DES", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("A", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("B", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 101, "ABC", "KIL", 1, 5 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 102, "XYZ", "LOU", 2, 6 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 103, "MNO", "HYT", 3, 7 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 104, "PQR", "HYT", 4, 8 });

            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt2.Columns.Add("ORG", typeof(string));
            dt2.Columns.Add("DES", typeof(string));
            dt2.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
            dt2.Columns.Add("B", typeof(int));

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
            {
                dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { row["ID"], row["ORG"], row["DES"], "A", row["A"] });
                dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { row["ID"], row["ORG"], row["DES"], "B", row["B"] });
            }


        }
    }



}
```

Comment: in above code, A, B is dynamic, sometime it comes as A,B,C or S,T or X,Y

Comment: You can use column number instead of column name.

Answer (score 0):

Have a for loop on DataTable-1 and use arrayList to fill data in it and then, convert it back to DataTable which will result in your required output.